# CSS not loading (404) when using HAML instead of ERB in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, erb

This ERB works (finds the CSS):

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "main" %>
```

but I'm converting my ERB to HAML and now my stylesheets are not found.  I could easily add something to `config/routes.rb` but I guess I shouldn't need to?

This is my HAML:

```
%link{:rel => "stylesheet", :type => "text/css", :href => "main"}
```

Is there not something like `stylesheet_link_tag` like in ERB?  The HAML looks worse than the ERB at the moment.  The rendered CSS looks like this with HAML:

```
<link href="main" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

so you can see why it can't find the file.

My CSS file is this: `app/assets/stylesheets/main.css`

Should I be using something like `stylesheet_link_tag` or do I have to alter my routes or something?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stylesheet_link_tag` is just a simple helper

in order to use it in haml just do something like this

```
= stylesheet_link_tag "main"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change it from:

```
%link{:rel => "stylesheet", :type => "text/css", :href => "main"}
```

to:

```
%link{rel => "stylesheet", :type => "text/css", :href => "main"}
```

You don't have to add the `:` to the `rel =>`

Comment: Why the downvote? If this does not fix the problem, change it anyway because it's wrong WITH a `:`.